# Identiify which user created the Continous Integration(CI) Build

Tags: continuous-integration

Am new to `TFS` and learning about CI.

Am going to `Team Explorer = > Builds` to see the list of build definitions created.

How do i identify who(**Which user**) has created that build definition ?

Am not getting where it is listed !! Hope it is available

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in TeamExplorer and I think there is no other way, because even in the database is not listed who created the build definition, only when it was created.

A strange workaround would be to check who changed the folder mappings of a build definition the last time, but this is only possible in database. I'm not very good in SQL and only spent few minutes to get this trashy statement:

```
SELECT ident.DisplayName
FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition] as bd, [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinitionWorkspace] as bdw, [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_IdentityMap] as im, [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_Identity] as ident
Where bd.DefinitionId = bdw.DefinitionId
and im.localId = bdw.LastModifiedBy
and ident.Id = im.masterId
and bd.DefinitionName like '%CodedUITests%'
```

The DefinitionName might not work well with special characters, but you can check in the database how it is written internaly.

Answer (score 1):

You could see who created/changes made to the underlying XAML files but the build definition as such is not exposed as a file in TFS now. So there is no history available. This has been requested as a new feature to MS but not sure when it will be available.

[LINK](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions)